# Topnav dropdown is not working in browser but does work in the w3schools editor?

Tags: html, css

I have relatively minimal experience with HTML and CSS but have been learning as I go along as I am building a website. Problem is that the navbar dropdown has stopped working but if I copy the code into a tool like W3schools it does work. I have been fiddling for hours and just need someone more experienced to tell me where i've gone wrong. Please see Index.html below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
awesome.min.css">
    <title>Ichor Studios</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     body 
     /*{
          background-image: url(Media/Background.png);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          background-size: cover;
        }


        }

/* Header/Logo Title */
.header {
   padding: 30px;
   background-position: center;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   font-size: 60px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color:#313131;
   background-size: cover;
 }
.footer {
   padding: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 10;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
   background-color:#313131;
   background-image: url("Media/footer.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #333;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
   float: left;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;
}
.active {
   background-color: #4CAF50;
   color: white;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn a {
   float: left;
   color: #f2f2f2;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 17px;

}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
   background-color: #4CAF50;
   color: white;
}
.dropdown {
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 99999;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
   font-size: 16px;  
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   color: white;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   background-color: inherit;
   font-family: inherit;
   margin: 0;

}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
   background-color: dimgrey;


}

.dropdown-content {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   min-width: 160px;
   box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   z-index: 99999;
}

.dropdown-content a {
   float: none;
   color: black;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
   z-index: 99999;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
   color: black;
   z-index: 99999;


}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;

</style>
```

```
<div class="header">ICHOR STUDIOS
</div>


<div class="topnav">
 <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Current Projects
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
 </button>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="oot2d.html">OOT2D</a>
  <a href="tower-defence.html">Tower Defence</a>
  <a href="the-delicious-prince.html">The Delicious Prince</a>
</div>
```

Update Logs
   FAQ's
   Contact
   About
  
  
 
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
     
    
     
     
      
     
     
     
      
     
     
     
      
     
     
     
      
     Previous   
    Next

This is test text which will describe the image above in a way that compels people
to 
    click and find out more about what we have to offer etc. This is test text which
will describe the 
    image above in a way that compels people to click and find out
more about what we have to offer 
    etc. 
    
      
      
    This is test text which will describe the image above in a way that compels people
to 
    click and find out more about what we have to offer etc. This is test text which
will describe the 
    image above in a way that compels people to click and find out
more about what we have to offer 
    etc.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-4.3.1.js"></script>
<!-------------------------------------------------------------SCRIPT FOR CAROUSEL END----------------------------------------------->
</style>
<link href="css/bootstrap-4.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
<div class="container">

<div class="sliding-background"></div>
<style type="text/css">
</div>
.container {
 overflow: hidden;
}


#container {
height: 100%;
width: 1920px;
position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
#leftcolumn {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: auto;
}
#rightcolumn {
float: right;
height: auto;
width: auto;

}
#container2 {
float: right;
height: 230px;
width: 1200px;
}
#rightcolumn-right {
padding-top: 16px;
float: right;
height: 200px;
width: auto;
}
#rightcolumn-left {
padding-top: 16px;
float: left;
height: 200px;
width: auto;
}



</div>  
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the problem that you are facing? What exactly is wrong with the header here?

Comment: In your last source code. You messed up with that. you added `div` in style instead of `body`. You didn't write that source code correctly.

Comment: the issue is that the dropdown menu which should appear under 'current project' does not show up in the browser.

i am really struggling here because at this stage it looks like a mess that i cant understand